# How to add Microdata to a DNN control with runat="server"?

Tags: jquery, dotnetnuke, microdata

I am using the Structured Data Markup Helper tool to highlight and select HTML elements with relevant data. I have the following problem.

DNN has a control that only loads the link and image on the onload event. (Brand Information)

```
<div class="dnn-logo">
    <dnn:LOGO runat="server" id="dnnLOGO" />
    <div class="LogoPane" id="LogoPane" runat="server" visible="false">
    </div>
</div>
```

The highlighter tool shows that I should add `itemprop="logo"` like so:

```
 <div class="dnn-logo"><a id="dnn_dnnLOGO_hypLogo" title="Our Company | Home" href="https://www.mywebsite.com/">
     <img itemprop="logo" id="dnn_dnnLOGO_imgLogo" src="/Portals/2/Images/logo.png" alt="Our Company | Home"/></a>
</div>
```

Must I use JQuery to somehow add the Microdata after everything has loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#<%= dnnLOGO.ClientID %>_imgLogo').attr("itemprop", "logo");

    });
</script>
```

Or you can simply edit the logo User Control. Located in `/Admin/Skins`

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Controls.Logo" CodeFile="Logo.ascx.cs" ViewStateMode="Disabled" %>

<asp:hyperlink id="hypLogo" runat="server">
    <asp:image id="imgLogo" runat="server" enableviewstate="False" itemprop="logo" />
</asp:hyperlink>
```